# 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: apt, proxy

When I try to install a software using Ubuntu Software center I get:

```
Failed to download repository information
Check Your Internet connection
```

When I try to do a `apt-get install something`, I get:

```
407  Proxy Authentication Required
```

I use a proxy server that requires a user-name and a password.
I have set my systems proxy manually, by plugging in the required numbers in the Networks proxy and applied it system wide. I guess the problem now is plugging in my user-name and password.

When I use INTERNET via Mozilla, it specifically asks me for my user-name and password.

Answer (score 54):

For your apt-get to work, you should edit your apt config file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

And add `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyhost:port/";`

The syntax shown above should be strictly followed.

This configuration may fail if your username or password has an '@' in it.
You can also add proxy configuration for other protocols such as FTP.

Update: If your username or password has '@' in it you can replace it with %40
Example:If your password is `@123` enter it as `%40123`.

For other characters see this [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: I did exactly what you said but it still gives me the same error. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I added the above proxy settings, but  now I am getting 404- Not Found, in place of 407- Proxy Authentication

Comment: What if my password contains a "@"?

Comment: On Xubuntu 19.10 I had to add a config file to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` like `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00proxy` since no general `/etc/apt/apt.conf` exists.

Comment: @Đēēpak I'd try [url percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Havent tested this on apt but this worked for special characters in proxy env variables.

Answer (score 12):

First set your proxy setting via Linux wizard use option manually and apply setting systemwide just like this wizard box.

Add your proxy environment. These are just example settings...
Open your command prompt login and edit the apt.conf file:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

There are already 4 lines of code starting with *Acquire* key word, edit it like this:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyhost:port/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://username:password@proxyhost:port/";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "ftp://username:password@proxyhost:port/";
```

**Note**
If your Password contains special characters like @,$,! (e.g. Password: P@ssword) then replace the special characters by their hex code equivalents with % prefix like this:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:p%40ssword@proxyhost:port/";
```

@==>%40
$==>%24
!==>%21

Comment: I added the above proxy settings, but now I am getting 404- Not Found, in place of 407- Proxy Authentication

Comment: What is the difference between first and fourth line????

Answer (score 5):

If you're behind an enterprise proxy that's running NTLM authentication, you could use CNTLM:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cntlm
$ sudo vi /etc/cntlm.conf
```

Change the default settings (domain, username, password and proxy). Then restart the service:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/cntlm restart
```

You can now use `localhost:3128` (default CNTLM port) as the system-wide proxy for Ubuntu.

Check http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/ for docs.

Comment: In order to get `sudo apt-get install cntlm` to work you first need to go through that proxy.

Answer (score 3):

If your user name is separated by space then use:

```
export http_proxy='http://Pankaj Kumar Pandit:ABCD@192.168.1.1:3128/'
```

If your user name is not separated by space then use:

```
export http_proxy=http://Pankaj_Kumar_Pandit:ABCD@192.168.1.1:3128/
```

The difference is the addition of opening and closing `'`.

Comment: who would  have username with spaces?

Answer (score 2):

I think this tutorial should help you.

> Click on Network tab select Manual Proxy Configuration option and enter your proxy server,port details.If you have username,password click on Authentication to enter these details click on ok

(from http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-desktop-to-use-your-proxy-server.html)

To invoke it for all programs launched in a shell I would suggest you either add it to your `/etc/bash.bashrc` using `gksudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc` to apply it system-wide for all bash sessions or to your user-space `~/.bashrc`.

As far as Synaptic goes, in the `Preferences` under the `Network` tab you seem to be able to set authentification for your proxies. This appears to be specific to Synaptic, though.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 11, can u help me in reaching synaptic

Comment: also where exactly in thie bash.bashrc does one need to plug in the username and password

Comment: `export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/`

Comment: i gave the command   sudo echo "export http_proxy=http://swastik:ramdayal@192.168.11.107:8081/" >> /etc/bash.bashrc              even now i get the same error

Answer (score 2):

One nice alternative is to use [Synaptic Package Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic)[image: Install Synaptic], where you can specify *system independent* proxy settings and also store username and password.

[image: Proxy Settings]

However, this *won't* change proxy for Software Center.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest versions of Ubuntu, you can use System Settings > Network > Network Proxy, and when you click `"apply system wide"` it modifies proxy settings in different places, at least including the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, HOWEVER...

It does not have any mechanism to prompt for authentication.  No idea why no one has made that part of it yet, but because of this, if you need authentication, you need to put your password and username there too in this format:

```
username:password@proxy.address
```

If your password or user name has any special characters in it, including `@` or `#` or `!` or whatever, you probably are going to have to use the HTML-ized character code for any of those special characters.  See this page for how you can that: http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html

Answer (score 1):

I have made a python script to set the proxy settings in Ubuntu

Assume the following setting, you need to replace at relevant places

- proxy_address 172.16.26.214
- proxy_port 3128
- proxy_username king
- proxy_password queen

I have made a video which takes you through all the steps:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBtzKa-dvJg

Steps are Detailed here:

- First click on Dash
- In Search Box Enter "Proxy" (Without Quotes)
- Click on "Network" under Applications
- Select "Network Proxy"
- Select Manual
- Enter the proxy address and proxy port
- Apply. Enter your system password to confirm

Download the script `setproxy.py`

https://pastebin.com/MbBHta8g

Let’s say you have saved the `setproxy.py` in the `Downloads` folder

- Open terminal
  Type
- cd ~/Downloads

General Command:
sudo python setproxy.py **proxy_address** **proxy_port** **proxy_username** **proxy_password**
For our example

- sudo python setproxy.py `172.16.26.214` `3128` `king` `queen`

In case of simple proxy Without authentication the command is:

- sudo python setproxy.py `172.16.26.214` `3128`

In case you have `python 3` and above run using `python2.7`
so the commands will look like

- sudo python2.7 setproxy.py `172.16.26.214` `3128`
- sudo python2.7 setproxy.py `172.16.26.214` `3128` `king` `queen`

Comment: Using dropbox or copy for storing scripts is very bad. You should use github, or paste.bin at least

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following commands.

For http connection - export:

```
http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy_server_address:port_no"
```

For https connection - export:

```
https_proxy="https://username:password@proxy_server_address:port_no"
```

And likewise for ftp and other connections.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I saved `apt.conf` created based on [jaseem's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/89360), to home directory instead of `/etc/apt` and specified the `-c` option in the apt command.

```
$ sudo apt -c=~/my-apt.conf update
```

You can also specify the configuration file path in the environment variable `APT_CONFIG`.

```
$ export APT_CONFIG=~/my-apt.conf
$ sudo apt update
```