# "E: Package ‘synaptic’ has no installation candidate" when trying to install synaptic

Tags: synaptic

```
ilshat@lpt:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done
Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package ‘synaptic’ has no installation candidate
```

- I have tried doing a `sudo apt-get update` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried installing it from the Software center ?

and try updating the repo by running `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: yes i have tried that also but it wont working.....i am new to ubuntu plz mind that also..

Comment: what your version of Ubuntu? ... please show `uname -s` output

Comment: @rohit most likely, you have **synaptic** installed already :)
try to type in lens 'syn'

Comment: @swift, not sure how `uname -s` is going to help here, should probably run `lsb_release -r` instead to find the version of Ubuntu

Comment: @swift, if it was already installed, it would return the message `synaptic is already the newest version.`, not the error he is receiving.

Comment: yes I'm do not against )) just want to say that I installed my Ubuntu, and it seems, synaptic was installed in distribution by default ...

Comment: @swift, that was in previous versions. Synaptic was removed from the default install for 11.10.

Comment: yes I seen ... strange, maybe I forget ... in 12.04 I have synaptic from start ...

Comment: Change your Mirror from software sources and try again.

Comment: @ swift -strange you got synaptic as default , because it was dropped from 11.04 , you can look [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/allpackages) synaptic is not present.

Comment: laugh))) i'm upgraded from beta ... synaptic was included to beta

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean

Answer (score 6):

**Synaptic** is available in the so-called **universe** repository. If you cannot find that package, it means that you do not have **universe** enabled. To enable it, follow these steps:

## GUI

Open **Software Sources** and select **Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)**

[image: Software Sources]

After doing so, you will be asked to reload the software sources and you will be ready to install your package.

## Terminal

Open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
sensible-editor /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And add the following three lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security universe
```

**Note:** I'm assuming that you are using Quantal (12.10). If this is not the case, then use `lsb_release -c` to find the codename of your Ubuntu release and replace `quantal` with that codename.

Then run `sudo apt-get update` and install **Synaptic**.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing `/etc/apt/sources.list` was not enough for me:

```
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
```

Then I did an `apt-get update`: got lots of invalid signature errors.

It was company's [proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88976/407-proxy-authentication-required).

Only then `apt-get update` worked and I could install packages again.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the repositories you are using don't have the synaptic package in them, but apt can see other packages refer to the synaptic package. What repository are you using? If you can change back to the defaults (archive.ubuntu.com) then do an `apt-get update` you should be able to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in Software & Updates (*Ubuntu Software* tab) *Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)* is enabled. Then install `synaptic` by running in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```