# Proxy authentication in the Software Center

Tags: apt, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [407 Proxy Authentication Required](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88976/407-proxy-authentication-required)

I'm trying to install a package on Ubuntu 12.04, but I get the error

> 407 Proxy Authentication Required

How can I configure the Software Center to use my proxy?

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/partner/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/source/Sources  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: How do you normally authenticate to your proxy? How did you set up the proxy in Ubuntu?