# Understanding the working of Apt Virtual HTTP Repository

Tags: apt, repository

My university has a virtual HTTP repository which we can access by changing our proxy to `10.1.1.224:3142`. Our regular proxy to access the internet is `10.1.8.44:8080`. It incredibly speeds up download speed with apt-get update and install commands.

Now sometimes I encounter various issues with my network connectivity when trying to use apt-get update or install with the repository, and I never know how to fix it or even try to figure out whats wrong since I have no understand of how it works.

So for a networking noob, can you explain how such virtual HTTP repository systems work? Do they have a storage of all packages? That seems a bit impossible. Or is it just sort of a gateway to access the Ubuntu repositories at unrestricted speeds? What happens if I change my repository server (in update manager) from say, Main servers to some other server? It still seems to work. And what happens if I add a custom PPA?

Here's a screenshot of the page that appears if I open `10.1.1.224:3142` when behind `10.1.8.44:8080`, if it helps you guys to understand what sort of proxy I'm talking about.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: No explanation for now, only a hint: always prefer editing/adding `/etc/apt/apt.conf` over changing your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @user1265125: What is is that you want to know that will solve your problem, if it is 407 authentication error, then you should refer this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88976/407-proxy-authentication-required. If you want a script that will set proxy in this file and also in dconf, I have script that may prove handy. Just confirm whether this is the exact nature of your problem.

Comment: @guntbert Yes I do add to apt.conf :).