# I can't install LibreOffice Base into Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on my USB.  I have everything from LibreOffice but the Base app.
When I search in the Software center it comes up and I click install but after 30 seconds it fails with this message:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jre-headless_6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
```

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jre_6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
```

(First two only as I need "reputation 12 to post more than 2 links")

What is happening?  Please keep in mind that I am a complete NOOBIE to Linux and Ubuntu!
Is there anyway I can get Base?  Or am I SOL? 
Thanks!

Comment: Though this is a 404 error, this could be a problem: Are you behind a proxy? If yes, refer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88976/407-proxy-authentication-required

Comment: @Jobin:  Not behind a proxy, directly though my ISP provider (Bell).

Comment: @Eliah Ok, I hope I've done this right:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1688214/plain/

Comment: I was actually trying to download Base from Ubuntu Software Center, cuz I'm a complete noob when it comes to using a Terminal.  Could the USC be the problem?  That shows ONLY the for "failed to fetch" lines and no other text.  Now I'm suspicious of the USC!

Comment: @Eliah The database portion of LibreOffice.  I've learned that for some reason BASE is not included in the LibreOffice package. I've seen the suggestion that it is because it is assumed that the average user won't use it, which sounds ridiculous to me.  Databases are great to create!  
So I search the Ubuntu Software Center (USC), as suggested, and then hit the install button.  POOF, 30 seconds later I get all those "failed to fetch" lines. 
I have never gotten those error messages B4.
If I can reach 10 reputation then I can post images!  Any easy way to get 1 more rep? :D

Comment: @Buskieboy You can post images anywhere on the web and provide the link, and we can add them for you. (But it looks like you may have enough rep now.) What happens if you open the Terminal and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base`? (Please provide the complete and exact text, you can use http://paste.ubuntu.com if it's too long.) And as [Lucio suggests](http://askubuntu.com/questions/257141/i-cant-install-libreoffice-base-into-ubuntu-12-04/258891#comment323793_258891), the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @Eliah As I said I am a complete noob at Linux and using a terminal.  I come from the land of lazy where everything is a button push away! :D
Ok, so I open the Terminal and put in that command as you have it here exactly, right?  
And after whatever happens let you know that result.  I assume I would do the cat/etc/sources.list separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the files it's trying to download *actually do not exist*.

This suggests that you have not run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

before running a command like `sudo apt-get install ...`.

So, try running `sudo apt-get update` first. That may fix this problem.

Comment: You are right. Actually *that* files doesn't exist. Your method should work, but if it doesn't, the OP should modify him source list..

Comment: @Lucio Why would that help? What do you think is wrong with `sources.list` that might cause this?

Comment: Because the updates system is looking for a non existing URI. I thought that it could be fixed from there.

Comment: @Lucio Sometimes it can. The domain name and package directory appear correct, though. So it seems likely APT is using old version information (which can be fixed by `sudo apt-get update`). As I cannot think of anything else so far, if that doesn't work, then it would probably be worthwhile to examine `sources.list`, but I can't think of anything very likely that would likely produce this specific error message, with those mostly correct (and probably formerly correct) URL's. Maybe sources for the wrong release (e.g., left over from a now-EoL release)?

Comment: @Eliah: Hazzah! The command line worked and it INCLUDED BASE!  Thank-you!

One odd thing though, after updating, I am now getting an odd error message about only having 150MG of disk space left (the amount varies with each message).  
If I am right to assume, I save on my USB stick instead of my hard drive right?  If so my 16GB USB should have enough space as I gave it the MAX 4GB* space. Why am I getting this message now?  Did I miss something? (should I start a new thread?)

*btw how can I increase that since it is a 16GB USB?