# How can I make squid-deb-proxy work with proxy authentication?

Tags: apt, proxy, cache, squid-deb-proxy

I have squid-deb-proxy working fine without a problem without apt proxy authentication. 
However when I add a proxy file to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` and put in my proxy authentication inside this file. Running sudo apt-get update does not work it misses the update and ignores.

However when I move out or comment the file that squid-deb-proxy-client created inside `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` which is 30autoproxy and contains 1 line pointing to `/usr/share/squid-deb-proxy-client/apt-avahi-discover` the APT-GET update works without a problem.

Note that observing the logs of `/var/log/squid-deb-proxy/access.log` does not log any successful entry. Going without proxy logs successful entries and apt-get update works.

So bottom line how to make squid-deb-proxy-client on the main ubuntu machine to work thru proxy that has authentication.

Comment: check this answer out http://askubuntu.com/a/89360/169736

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your question. Is your squid-deb-proxy server behind a proxy which needs authentication? Or do you want you squid-deb-proxy clients to authenticate against the squid-deb-proxy server?

In the former case, I put `cache_peer proxy.acme.corp parent 8080 0 no-query default login=username:password` in `/etc/squid-deb-proxy/squid-deb-proxy.conf`.