# Unable to use proxy in terminal despite apt.conf file

Tags: apt, internet, proxy, connection

I use a wired LAN at my college which uses proxy. As per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/89360/255354) I edited my `apt.conf` file. My proxy details are as follows

**Username:** mahe\ict.student

**Password:** mumit@123

**Proxy host:** 172.16.19.10

**Port:** 80

This is my `apt.conf` file.

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://mahe%5Cict%2Estudent:mumit%40123@172.16.19.10:80/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://mahe%5Cict%2Estudent:mumit%40123@172.16.19.10:80/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://mahe%5Cict%2Estudent:mumit%40123@172.16.19.10:80/";
```

I still get the same 407 Proxy Authentication error. I posted my details here because I read that there are issues with Proxy authentication where username/password contain special characters like @. Is there anything wrong in the configuration above? How do I use the proxy on the terminal?