# installing synaptic package manager from outside the repos

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center, proxy, synaptic

I have been facing some problems in installing software with ubuntu software center, due to the fact that I have not been able to run no proxy for the whole system, I have tried all methods prescribed in various websites to do the same but i always get `407  Proxy Authentication Required`. So I want to install synaptic package manager through source code or .deb file which can be downloaded from the internet and then installed manually. Please post the link from which the same can downloaded and also steps to install it manually. A little detail would be of great help as I am a beginner and unaware of the nuances.

As suggested in one of the answers when i download the .deb package and perform
`sudo dpkg -i synaptic_0.81.2_amd64.deb` in the terminal this is what happens...

[image]

I am not able to make out where there has been a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can download synaptic package manager .deb file, and install it.  Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded, probably the Downloads folder, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>.deb
```

Click for [32bit](https://copy.com/rToHrARrvdSF), and [64bit](https://copy.com/QOsxondWKK6E) depending on your architecture.  Or you can download and build from [source](https://copy.com/Uz9ZToo28sPy).

You may want to take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88976/407-proxy-authentication-required) for the Authentication issue.

Take a look at [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/synaptic), and see if works that way.

Comment: please look at the recent edit in the question...i tried your method but it gives some sort of an error.

Comment: I tried here, and it installed without any errors.  Try to do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, and try it again.

Comment: But to do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` i need a net with a no proxy and i dont have that privilege right nw.

Comment: Synaptic has been installed; however, the dependencies have not been installed. Normally, doing an `apt-get install -f` fixes this, but considering you have some proxy issues...  I take it you tried telling `apt` about your proxy?

Comment: @saiarcot895 yes i have tried that too .... but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Have you tried to download and build from source?  Also look at what I've added in my answer.