# 407 Proxy Authentication Required - apt

Tags: networking, apt, proxy, authentication

My school network is behind a proxy server in which from campus, if I want to update my system through apt, I need to use authentication. For this I have created the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf` which contains the proxy authentication information as follows:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@server:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "http://username:password@server:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "http://username:password@server:port/";
```

Also, my password contains the special character `$` which I have replaced with `%24` from online recommendations. After running the command `sudo apt-get update` I am still getting the error:

```
407  Proxy Authentication Required
```

But I know my credentials are correct as I am able to login for normal browsing in Chrome/Firefox. Any ideas or suggestions on solving this problem?

Comment: hey, did you try this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/88976/407-proxy-authentication-required?rq=1

Comment: Yea, I alreaddy tried that and I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: What exactly did you add to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`? Is it the text from your question, or some specific server and port?

Comment: The text from my question with my specific username and password with the specified proxy address and port.